# Code cannot find square number (python beginner)

Tags: python

Hi im a complete beginner can anyone help me out why is my code not functioning?

-trying to whether the number is a square number (true / false)

```
import math 

def is_square(n): 

    if n >= 0:
        if math.sqrt (n).is_integer :
            print (n,"is a square number")
            return True
            
        else:
            print (n," is not a square number ")
            return False
          
    else: 
        print ( n,":","Negative numbers cannot be square numbers")
        return False
```

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting? Is it not working for a particular input? If yes, what is the input?

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `math.sqrt (n).is_integer` to mean?

Comment: You need to use `is_integer()` instead of `is_integer`. However, this will not solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Check if a number is a square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531084/python-check-if-a-number-is-a-square)

Comment: I understand my mistake abt math.sqrt returning a floating number but out of curiosity what is the difference between is_integer() instead of is_integer ? Thanks btw for taking time to comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax:
`variable. is_integer()`

```
import math 

def is_square(n): 

    if n >= 0:
        if math.sqrt (n).is_integer() : # you need to call the .is_integer method
            print (n,"is a square number")
            return True
            
        else:
            print (n," is not a square number ")
            return False
          
    else: 
        print ( n,":","Negative numbers cannot be square numbers")
        return False
is_square(-4)
is_square(4)
is_square(5)
```

```
-4 : Negative numbers cannot be square numbers
4 is a square number
5  is not a square number
```

To get better insight, try getting the output:

```
print(math.sqrt (5).is_integer(), '\n' ,math.sqrt (5).is_integer)
```

```
False 
 <built-in method is_integer of float object at 0x7f320fba2360>
```

Comment: `math.sqrt((90000000**2)+3).is_integer()` will result in False. So this may not work.

Comment: because 90000000.00000001 is not an `int`

Comment: sorry, I meant `math.sqrt((70000000**2)+1).is_integer()` will result in True. That's not correct. Any large number will give True. Another example `math.sqrt((90000000**2)+1).is_integer()`

Comment: This is an edge case and for a precision greater than 10^-9 I think math module is not it

Comment: how would it be True. If `(70000000**2)` is an int when we do square root, how will adding 1 to it make it still an integert?

Answer (score 1):

`math.sqrt (n)` returns a float number. For example, `math.sqrt(144)` would give you `12.0`. so, `is.integer()` method won't work.
Try adding this piece of code:

```
if n >= 0:
        p=math.sqrt(n)
        if p==int(p):
            print (n,"is a square number")
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

here are some examples:

```
>>> 12==int(12)
True
>>> 12.0==int(12.0)
True
>>> 12.3==int(12.3)
False
```