# Finding Triangle numbers in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need help to find numbers in list if it's triangle number or not and if it's triangle number, 1(string format), else 0(also string format).

For Example:

Input: n = [3, 4, 6, 55, 345]

Output: "10110"

Another Example:

Input: n = [0, 1, 2, 5]

Output: "1100"

Thanks in advance.

I am using Python 3.12.

Here's my code:

```
n = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91, 105, 120, 136, 153, 171, 190, 210, 231, 253, 276, 300, 325, 351, 378, 406, 435, 465, 496, 528, 561, 595, 630, 666, 703, 741, 780, 820, 861, 903, 946, 990, 1035]
a = int(input())
b = list(map(int,input().split()))
d = ""
for i in b:
    if i in n:
        d += "1"
    else:
        d += "0"
print(d)
```

But it's limited by 1035. Is there any way to check it without using list? Maximum number is can be input is 10^8.

Comment: How do you define triangle numbers?

Comment: @NewbieCoder what is the maximum limit of a number to check whether it is a triangular number or not?

Comment: @Goku It's 10^8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A triangular number or triangle number counts objects arranged in an equilateral triangle. Triangular numbers are a type of figurate number, other examples being square numbers and cube numbers. The nth triangular number is the number of dots in the triangular arrangement with n dots on each side, and is equal to the sum of the n natural numbers from 1 to n

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Top 20000 triangle numbers.. Similarly you can increase the limit depending upon your need.

As @Kelly suggested keep the elements in `set`

```py
from itertools import accumulate
limit = 20000
a = set(accumulate(range(1, limit+1)))
```

---

For your question you can do:

```
n = [3, 4, 6, 55, 345]

''.join('1' if x in a else '0' for x in n )

#output
'10110'
```

Comment: If you're going to precalculate them, better put them into a set.

Answer (score 4):

You can know whether a number  is triangular by checking if there is a positive integer  such  = (+1)/2. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number#Triangular_roots_and_tests_for_triangular_numbers) mentions, this means that:

> ...an integer  is triangular if and only if 8 + 1 is a square.

Using that we can have this function:

```
def is_triangular(x):
    square = 8*x + 1
    return round(square ** 0.5) ** 2 == square
```

Solving the challenge is now a matter of calling this function on each given input.

Comment: If imports are allowed for the exercise, one could maybe do `return math.isqrt(square) ** 2 == square` to avoid floating point precision issues with large numbers. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66191905/765091)